# Hydra: how to use variable interpolation in packaged configs

Tags: fb-hydra, omegaconf

I have some config file, `model/foo.yaml`:

```yaml
# @package _global_
# foo.yaml
MODEL:
  BACKBONE:
    OUT_FEATURES: [c4, c5]
  HEAD:
    IN_FEATURES: ${MODEL.BACKBONE.OUT_FEATURES}
```

There are no issues with variable interpolation when I point to this config in the defaults-list of another config, eg `buzz.yaml`, *except* when I also override the package like so:

```yaml
# buzz.yaml
defaults:
  - model@foo_head: foo
```

Attempting to compose `buzz.yaml`, you will get an error like:

```
omegaconf.errors.InterpolationKeyError: Interpolation key 'MODEL.BACKBONE.OUT_FEATURES' not found
```

Can variable interpolation not be used in configs when packaging?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. OmegaConf supports [relative interpolation](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/2.1_branch/usage.html#config-node-interpolation).

```yaml
MODEL:
  BACKBONE:
    OUT_FEATURES: [c4, c5]
  HEAD:
    IN_FEATURES: ${..BACKBONE.OUT_FEATURES}
```

I strongly recommend that you read the docs of OmegaConf.